# How to make function arguments options?

Tags: php, function, parameters

If you have a function like so:

```
function somefunc ($data, $something) {
//
}
```

When you call the function like this:

```
somefunc($data);
```

it sends error saying it is missing argument 2. Is there a way to make the second argument optional? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function somefunc ($data, $something = null) {
//
}
```

Comment: You could even have $something = '', though Null probably is a better solution.

Answer (score 7):

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php):

**Default argument values**

A function may define C++-style default values for scalar arguments as follows:

Example #3 Use of default parameters in functions

```
<?php
function makecoffee($type = "cappuccino")
{
    return "Making a cup of $type.\n";
}
echo makecoffee();
echo makecoffee(null);
echo makecoffee("espresso");

?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Making a cup of cappuccino.
Making a cup of .
Making a cup of espresso.
```

Comment: A secondary effect of this answer is actually craving coffee after reading it - A cunning tactic!

Answer (score 0):

For this I like to use arrays as parameters. It's one of the things PHP does very well.

```
function foo(array $options = array())
{
      // you can set the defaults here
      $default = array('data'=>false,'something'=>'whatever');
      $options = array_merge($default,$options);
}
```

Since the `foo()` function applies defaults to the array you no longer have to perform a `isset()` check to see if a key is missing.

You can call `foo()` like this.

```
foo(); // pure defaults
foo(array('data'=>'stuff'));
```